# Android - Bitmap OCR

Tags: java, android, bitmap, ocr, bufferedimage

I get this problem:

```
The type java.awt.image.RenderedImage cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I know it means that there is no reference to it in my build-path and I heard that java.awt.image is not in the Android SDK. So I am trying to figure out how to work around it.

This is my code:

```
Bitmap image = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
String text = new OCR().recognizeEverything(image);
```

Obviously you can see that I am trying to use a OCR library. If it is impossible to get around this then can anyone show me a reference to maybe a "how to make an OCR program" or something along those lines. I pretty much have NO experience with images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your OCR library uses `java.awt` classes internally, you can't use it on Android. Porting it to use Android classes instead is likely to be non-trivial, especially if you have no experience. [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/) library is being actively developed, and is reported to work on Android (I haven't personally used it). You might want to give it a try. Also, searching helps too: this is a fairly frequent question on SO, you might get some other ideas from previous answers.

Comment: I think I might have to port it. I have searched ALOT and couldn't find anything relevant to my needs. Thanks for your ideas mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

We are developing  pure java OCR library here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

At the moment, there is some image processing stuff,  invariant moment based recognition
and high performance binarisation.  There are also demos schowcasing complete roundtrip for android ( gathering samples,   performing recognizer training,  performing reconigtion )

I already published 2 appluications based on it:

http://www.pribluda.de/android/charger/
http://www.pribluda.de/android/ocrcall/